# Ayuda con funcion en c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Tengo un problema con un una función que dejo el programador anterior.

Tenemos la función que valida si un usuario existe en BD, hasta aquí todo normal, la duda radica cuando empieza la consulta en linq invocando el sp `PRC_GET_USAURIO_LOG`, lo que infiero es que luego de que el usuario se conecta si existe escribe en x tabla los datos del usuario que se conecta y luego `PRC_GET_USAURIO_LOG` ¿hace una consulta?

Pd: No aparece ese sp en la db, por eso ando como perdido con esta funcion.

Adjunto la función.

```
if (Objlibreria.Validar_Usuario("", this.txtusuario.Text, this.txtcontrasena.Password.ToString(), aplicacion))
                        {
                            using (var En = new DB_SEntities())
                            {
                                var UsuarioLogeado = En.PRC_GET_USUARIO_LOG(txtusuario.Text.ToString(), txtcontrasena.Password.ToString(), aplicacion).FirstOrDefault();
                                if (UsuarioLogeado != null)
                                {
                                    SessionManager.UsuarioLoguedo = UsuarioLogeado.CEDULA;
                                    SessionManager.Estado = UsuarioLogeado.ESTATUS;
                                    SessionManager.Perfil = UsuarioLogeado.DPERFIL;
                                    SessionManager.Aplicacion = UsuarioLogeado.APLICACION;
                                    SessionManager.NombreUsuario = UsuarioLogeado.NOMBRE.Trim()+" "+ UsuarioLogeado.APELLIDO.Trim();
                                    SessionManager.Almacen = UsuarioLogeado.ALMACEN;
                                    SessionManager.DAlmacen = UsuarioLogeado.DALMACEN;
                                    Parametros.Calmacen = UsuarioLogeado.ALMACEN;
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: A simple vista, lo que realiza es que obtiene información del usuario logueado y si la encuentra, la asigna a sesión manager para tener disponible siempre esa información. Me imagino que la usará para mostrar por ejemplo el usuario que se encuentra logueado en pantalla o/y otro tipo de información correspondiente a dicho usuario

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Gracias por responder, claro tienes razón, pero mi duda radica es en el prc_get_usuario_log, lo que yo creo es que vuelve y realiza otra consulta y ya de hay trae la info y la almacena, creeria que es asi no?

Comment: que hace Objlibreria.Validar_Usuario() ? solo verifica que los campos obligatorios tengan datos o tambien consulta la db

Comment: Mira, la función **Validar_Usuario** lo más probable es que valida las credenciales del usuario y despues en el sp **prc_get_usuario_log** trae la info del usuario logueado para trabajarla de alguna manera (como mostrarla en pantalla como te mencioné)

Comment: @LeandroTuttini `Objlibreria.Validar_Usuario` verifica que el usuario existe y que sus credenciales esten ok

Comment: pero entonces es lo mismo que hace el linq cuando invoca el procedure PRC_GET_USUARIO_LOG, valida que el usuario y password sean coincidentes, no tiene sentido ese Validar_Usuario()

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Lo que infiero es que hay doble validación la de `Objlibreria` valida que el usuario este en base de datos y la credenciales ok, luego "supongo" que cuando se hace esta validación se escribe un log en x tabla que ya es la que `prc_get_usuario_log` leeria

Comment: Ignoro realmente lo que hace el sp, a mi parecer obtiene información adicional del usuario solamente, pero sin ver el procedimiento ni saber la estructura, estaría divagando.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Eso mismo pensé, luego divagando supuse que en la primera validación, escribe en una tabla log, que seria la que el `prc_get_usuario_log` lee luego

Comment: De hecho Validar_Usuario devuelve un `bool`... deberías modificar eso para que te devuelva el **objeto (usuario)** completo y así te evitas llamar al procedimiento

Comment: no tiene mucho sentido validar usuario\password para luego leerlo desde una tabla de log, esta bastante extraño. Lo que puedes hacer es validar el usuario\password devoliendo los datos del usuario o quizas el usuarioId (y con este obtienes el resto de la informacion), sino existe devuelve null, entonces no autenticas